# How does one identify an empty element using jQuery that might contain a comment tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to identify an empty element that might or might not contain a comment tag and/or white space.

The following HTML structure is common place in the environment I'm working with:

```
<div class="container container-no-title">
  <div id="dnn_ctr6735_ContentPane" class="container-padding DNNAlignright">
    <!-- Start_Module_6735 -->
    <div id="dnn_ctr6735_ModuleContent">
      <!-- End_Module_6735 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My initial jQuery was:

```
$('.container-padding > div').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":empty")) {
    $(this).parent('.container-padding').remove();
  };
});
```

But this doesn't account for whitespace or comment tags. I found other questions that addressed whitespace, but nothing that addresses comment tags, and I'd really like to keep this little snippet of jQuery simple.

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$('.container-padding > div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().match(/^\s*$/)) {
        $(this).parent('.container-padding').remove();
    }
});
```

Or even

```
$('.container-padding').each( function() {
    if ($(this).text().match(/^\s*$/)) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have, that addressed of the whitespace, but didn't address the comment tag.

Comment: Then why not add a regex test for the comment tag and be done with it?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to remove the element if there is a comment tag?  In my test with your example, this successfully matched and removed the inner container.

Comment: that second solution hit the nail on the head... very much appreciated.

Comment: I have to give you full credit - this solution presented another issue, but you certainly provided the correct answer to the question...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly an empty element should have no children:

`$(this).children().length == 0`

Would'nt jQuery do the work of ignoring whitespace and comments for you?

Comment: I think the idea was that it if it contained only an empty child, comments, or whitespace, it should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

glad that tv's solution worked for you.  you can also use straight up DOM to find nodes that aren't "elements" by checking the nodeType value.

for example, iterating over element.childNodes:

```
if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType != 1)
// node is not an element (text/whitespace or comment)
```

or:

```
if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 8)
// node is a comment
```

check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodes_info.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are not part of the DOM tree, so AFAIK there's no way you could access them.

Comment: This is a nice flat answer and worthy of some applause, but I can't believe there isn't a solution to this!